# TFS 2015: Task often/always disappears from build definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'll add a task for tokenization (https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack) to my build definition and the build definition will execute and do everything exactly as expected. However, if I were to reopen the build-definition, the new task will be missing (even though it's actively being used in builds).

If I were to add a task of a different type it will show up as expected on future visits. I've not used this VSIX/task very much, but I've used (read: added-executed-viewed) with this task at least once in the recent past and this did not happen. So, this doesn't necessarily happen every time. It looks like the same general issue affects more than one task installed from this same VSIX. Any suggestions and where to go from here for testing/debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look about custom task with below info：

- Currently only ‘**Agent Pool Administrators**’ are able to add/update
  or remove tasks.
- Tasks are server-wide, this means that you will upload to the
     server, not to a specific collection or project.

According to your description, first thing that pops to mind is that the task category is incorrect (non-existing or invisible). Visibility tells you what kind of task it is, possible values are: Build, Release and Preview. Currently only Build-type tasks are shown.

More detail info about custom build task, please refer this link: [vsts-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks)

Comment: Note that the question states that it *is* visible initially and becomes *invisible* after the save.

Comment: Think that's a bug in TFS. It ought not be visible at all, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with the On Premises Tasks (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=technossusllc.on-premises-build-tasks), such as the Database Deployment task.

I can add the task (it shows up), it will perform, but about 75% of the time, when I edit my build definition, the Undo button lights up immediately (before I do anything), and I can see that my task (Database deploy) was removed. If I hit Undo, it comes back.  What process is removing tasks?

Comment: I don't think they're being removed and I 'don't think it's another process. I think it's a bug that relates to extension (read: non-builtin) tasks. It still runs, it just ceases to be visible. The fact that Microsoft, themselves, created the VSIX whose task I'm having issues with makes me think that it's a TFS problem. I doubt there's some property in the task JSON definition that can culminate in this bug and I would expect Microsoft (as the SMEs) to at least create a task correctly (even if everything else has bugs).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when the extension itself was coded to be visible only to 'Release'.

You can see this in the task.json under the 'visibility' key:

```
{
    "id": "3311DF41-0CBE-467C-A1EB-6007DFACDCEC",
    "name": "MyExt",
    "friendlyName": "My Extension",
    "description": "This is my extension",
    "helpMarkDown": "[Link]",
    "category": "Utility",
    "visibility": [
        "Build",
    ],
    ....
```

TFS will allow these to be added in, and in some instances will display them. A bit of a bug there methinks.

Fortunately, I had control of the task JSON, so created a new version with the following:

```
    ....
    "visibility": [
        "Build",
        "Release"
    ],
    ....
```